# JWPlayer mp3 playlist does not auto load next track

Tags: html, mp3, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using JWPlayer for a long time but have a problem with playlist not auto loading next tracks in iPhones. I have JWPlayer version 6 loaded with an rss playlist of MP3 files. If the user has the browser open the next track loads and starts playing. If the phone is locked it does not start playing the next track automatically for some reason.

Website: gurbanivichar.com

I would appreciate if someone can help.

---

Update

I have asked JWPlayer support for help but it seems like they are not able to replicate the issue for some reason. I on the other hand have this issue on iPhone 4s/5/6s/7 and iPad, other iPhones I have not tried.

JWPlayer support thread: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/16729726-mp3-playlist-auto-play-next-tracks-in-iphone?new=16729726

If you can help be reproducing the issue, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated this issue thoroughly and found that this because of iPhone/iPad limitation that apple has put in. The limitation stops audio/video to autoplay without any interaction. The initial trigger has to come from the user.

So due to this, I have decided to allow users to download an m3u playlist to play on an audio player on the device such as Remote Media Manager, it allows an M3U from any URL to stream music from the web.

Thanks for your help.